# SHA256 security question

Tags: security, math, sha256, sha

Having that the result for some string STR was:

```
SHA256(STR)=3f7c54571faee024e3fd68603c5c95f6a4c8ef73a398840b974f3f57737a116f
```

Would it be possible to get the result of `SHA256(myOwnString+STR)`? ('+' is used as concatenation)

Are there any known attacks for this scenario?

Comment: Secure hash algorithms are explicitly designed to prevent that, though of course it is always possible that a successful attack (successful = considerably faster than brute force) is found. So far, no attacks that are reasonable are known, "reasonable" meaning as much as "possible with our understanding of physics".

Comment: It's not clear from what point of view you're asking this. But if you're trying to ensure message authenticity, you should really use a HMAC (or even a public key based signature). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC This should guard against the case that a collision attack is found against SHA-256.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myOwnString+STR` would be a totally different string than `STR` -- so, those two would have totally different hashes ; and looking at those hashed, you'd have no way of guessing they result of your hashing function being applied to `STR` and something based on `STR`.

That's precisely why we generally recommend using a salt when hashing passwords -- see [Salt (cryptography)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29), about that.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is evaluating hash function's 'avalanche property';  if you change the input just a little bit, how much does the output change?  Any decent hashing function should be able to completely mangle the result drastically even if the input changes just one bit.  This is why things like salts and nonces work well, because adding few bytes to the initial string (which by itself might be weak, short or predictable, like passwords), changes the result of the hash to something completely different and unrelated to the original.

to answer your question more directly tho:

> A 2008 attack breaks preimage
>   resistance for 46 out of 80 rounds of
>   SHA-512, and 41 out of 64 rounds of
>   SHA-256.[1] Collision attacks against
>   up to 24 steps of SHA-256

and

> There are two meet-in-the-middle preimage attacks against SHA-2 with a reduced number of rounds. The first one attacks 41-round SHA-256 out of 64 rounds with time complexity of 2253.5 and space complexity of 216, and 46-round SHA-512 out of 80 rounds with time 2511.5 and space 23. The second one attacks 42-round SHA-256 with time complexity of 2251.7 and space complexity of 212, and 42-round SHA-512 with time 2502 and space 222.

So yes, it's weakened, but it's nowhere near useless yet.  And I haven't found any attacks specific to dealing with input length extension.